# Adobe AIR Scrolling Performance on iPad (2) - What Can I Expect?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, apache-flex, ipad, air

I'm currently working on an Adobe AIR application which is targeting the iPad2 as the hardware platform, and can not get decent scrolling performance on one of the screens. I'm using a spark list, with a custom item renderer like so:

```
<s:List id="productList" top="116" bottom="0" left="10" right="10" 
    width="100%"
    visible="true" includeInLayout="true"
    height="0"
    maxHeight="500"
    opaqueBackground="#ffffff"
    itemRenderer="myRenderer">
</s:List>
```

Originally, I was using an .mxml renderer, but after seeing the nasty performance I decided to roll my own, extending UIComponent (I've left off the package and braces to save on horizontal space):

```
import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;
import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
import mx.utils.ColorUtil;

import spark.components.Label;
import spark.components.TextInput;

public final class OrderViewProductLineTestIR extends UIComponent implements IListItemRenderer 
{
    public function OrderViewProductLineTestIR()
    {
        super();
    }

    // Internal variable for the property value.
    private var _data:Object;

    private var productName:Label;
    private var orderQty:TextInput;
    private var stockQty:TextInput;


    // Make the data property bindable.
    [Bindable("dataChange")]

    // Define the getter method.
    public function get data():Object
    {
        return _data;
    }

    // Define the setter method, and dispatch an event when the property
    // changes to support data binding.
    public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        _data = value;
        invalidateProperties();
        dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();

        productName = new Label();
        // productName.visible = true;
        addChild(productName);

        orderQty = new TextInput();
        addChild(orderQty);

        stockQty = new TextInput();
        addChild(stockQty);

    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void
    {
        super.commitProperties();
        productName.text = _data.Name;
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        productName.move(0, 0);
        productName.setActualSize(250, 48);

        orderQty.move(270, 0);
        orderQty.setActualSize(100, 48);

        stockQty.move(390, 0);
        stockQty.setActualSize(100, 48);
    }

    override protected function measure():void
    {
        super.measure();

        measuredWidth = 490;
        measuredHeight = 48; 
    }
}
```

As you can see this is pretty light-weight, yet my dataprovider contains upwards of 100 items, and 11 of them can be on screen at any one time. Everything I've read around increasing performance for scrolling revolves around using `opaqueBackground` and `cacheAsBitmap`, however no matter what I try neither help here. Using `cacheAsBitmap` at the list level doesn't help as the item renderer recycling kicks in once you've scrolled more than a couple of lines requiring the whole thing to be re-rendered, and using it at the item renderer level is still horribly slow when scrolling fast — presumably because many are being recycled at once during a very fast scroll.

I know the iPad should have no problem blitting a screenful of information in a frame at 60 fps, yet when I scroll quickly I'm seeing it struggle to make 10 fps (from sight). So the question: **have I missed something obvious, or is this to be expected due to the number of layers (and vector rendering) involved when using AIR?** For the record, I have tried changing the render mode for the application and tried changing the frame rate to eliminate the obvious.

Comment: One quick thing you may want to try. In your case it doesn't look like you need to call super from your overrides. Honestly though you're not going to get native performance out of the Spark list. If you have the flexibility you may want to checkout the foxhole GPU components: https://github.com/joshtynjala/foxhole-starling.

Comment: Not cacheAsBitmap, for mobile you want cacheAsBitmapMatrix. See http://www.riagora.com/2010/09/bitmap-caching-for-android/. But even at that... I often remind people that the flash virtual machine is terribly bad. There is a reason why Steve Jobs didn't want it on his devices. I don't want to start a fanboysim fight here, I'm not a fanboy of apple or flash, I'm just saying the truth. Adobe posted a benchmark on LLVM.org showing that AS3 performance is about 1% the efficiency of native C and it peaks with LLVM optimization (sporadically) to 30 percent.

Comment: Also I'm curious what version of AIR you're building against. See the following post, it may be of some help to you http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=2754.

Comment: I tried cacheAsBitmapMatrix using an identity matrix, unfortunately it caused some blurring to the image for some reason — seems like the poly rendered to wasn't mapping 1:1 with the view port.

I suspected that it's just a case of Adobe bloat killing it dead :( I'm using AIR 3.2 and Flex 4.6

Comment: @shaunhusain you missed a word there :) From what I've read UIComponent is the lightest base to extend...

Comment: @LaceySnr I feel your pain. I was a flash developer for about 6 years and then I moved to C++ because the flash platform has so much potential but just falls short every time... killed my dreams. lol I'm back to working with AIR again myself for the first time in a year and it's so painful. I like C++ because if something isn't working right or I need more/better functionality, I can just write it myself and run pedal-to-the-metal straight to the hardware. Anyway sorry I couldn't be of any real help I suspect that your conclusion here is right.

Comment: if you want perfectly fluid animations with mobile Flash/AIR, you can create your own scroll list component using the Stage3D API, which is now available for mobile AIR since version 3.2.  check out the Starling Framework.  Stage3D, as far as i'm concerned, has redefined Flash.  it's super fast.

Comment: Only problem with Starling is that it doesn't have text input fields — might be possible to roll my own but the time invested would be pretty excessive. Will check out the code for a look anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of guessing, but can the itemRenderer be optimized?  Do all the children need to be positioned and sized every time component redraws?  Do you need to update productName.text every time commitProperties run?

Here is how I might modify things:

```
import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;
import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
import mx.utils.ColorUtil;

import spark.components.Label;
import spark.components.TextInput;

public final class OrderViewProductLineTestIR extends UIComponent implements IListItemRenderer 
{
    public function OrderViewProductLineTestIR()
    {
        super();
    }

    // Internal variable for the property value.

private var _data:Object;

// Add a dataChanged property 
private var dataChanged :Boolean = false

private var productName:Label;
private var orderQty:TextInput;
private var stockQty:TextInput;


// Make the data property bindable.
[Bindable("dataChange")]

// Define the getter method.
public function get data():Object
{
    return _data;
}

// Define the setter method, and dispatch an event when the property
// changes to support data binding.
public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    _data = value;
    // switch the dataChanged flag 
    dataChanged = true;
    invalidateProperties();
    dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
}

override protected function createChildren():void
{
    super.createChildren();

    productName = new Label();
    // productName.visible = true;
    addChild(productName);

    orderQty = new TextInput();
    addChild(orderQty);

    stockQty = new TextInput();
    addChild(stockQty);

}

override protected function commitProperties():void
{
    super.commitProperties();
    // Only update the display if the data actually changed 
    If(dataChanged){
      productName.text = _data.Name;
      dataChanged = false;
    }
}


// add variable to tell whether the component's children have been sized and positioned or not
// since they have static locations, no need to set these each time
protected var compChildrenSized :Boolean = false;
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    if(!compChildrenSized){
     productName.move(0, 0);
     productName.setActualSize(250, 48);

     orderQty.move(270, 0);
     orderQty.setActualSize(100, 48);

     stockQty.move(390, 0);
     stockQty.setActualSize(100, 48);

     compChildrenSized = true;
    }
}

override protected function measure():void
{
    super.measure();

    measuredWidth = 490;
    measuredHeight = 48; 
}
}
```

I guess I'll add that I'm not sure measure will ever run.  What happens if you replace the textInputs with labels?  Are you using Flex 4.6, and if so are you using StyleableStageText (AKA StageText) or the 4.5 skin which uses StyleableTextField?  I wonder if StageText scrolling could kill performance because it hangs out above the Flash Display list.

What happens if you remove the textInput completely and replace with labels?

These are little things, and I'm not sure if they'll help.

Comment: Tried the above but to no avail, although the code is definitely more optimal I think the bottleneck is farther down the stack — most likely just in Adobe's layers of code beneath. Thanks for the input though, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try just this on your "Spark List component"
1/ add a layout (horizontal or vertical depending on what you want ;)
2/ add attribute "useVirtualLayout=true" on your list component !

And tell me what's the result ... but i think it will be smoother (very very smoother),
because when you add your elements to the list, all the components are rendered, even if
they are out of the layout ... so whith "useVirtualLayout" just items that are on the viewport are rendered others are destroyed ...

See ya ! and have fun whith Flash Builder ! it's a so cool technology to have a multi support app !

Comment: Had a crack at this but made no difference, pretty sure it was already recycling the cells. Don't understand how such a powerful device can be brought to it's knees like this!

Answer (score -1):

A bit late. but.

Its true that its better to use starling and feather if you want something close to native performance.

But you can still optimise your renderer.
Please dont use binding anywhere in a Flex mobile application.
Extending UIComponent is the right thing to do.
I think it would be better to not use invalidation and set your properties in the data setter.

Hope it helps.